# Xamarin iOS: navigation bar not showing after pushing view

Tags: ios, xamarin, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

I have created all of my UI in code (since I use [Flyout Navigation](https://components.xamarin.com/view/flyoutnavigation) which doesn't seem to work with storyboards). I have a UINavigationController called `MainController`, and a series of view controllers. When I start up the app with the root controller, it displays the navigation bar just fine.

When I programmatically create a new ViewController called `ArticleDisplay`, I create and push it as such (within MainController):

```
public void Open_Article(Post post)
{
    ArticleDisplay vw = new ArticleDisplay(this);
    vw.SetPost(post); // to set the iOS

    this.PushViewController(vw, true);
}
```

When I run the app and display the ArticleDisplay controller, I don't get a navigation bar ([as you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km6Vt.png)), although the main view controller has a navigation bar. Trying to do things like `this.SetNavigationBarHidden(false,true)` do nothing.

What do I do to get the navigation bar to display? I'm sure I'm screwing it up somewhere. I need it so I can allow the user to get back to the controller they were in before.

Comment: It might be that the Flyout Navigation controller is the one that's keeping a navigation stack. Check if the NavigationController has value within the pushed controller, there is a property called ViewControllers that displays the navigation stack.

Comment: try.. this.PushViewController(new UINavigationController(vw), true)

Comment: @MohibSheth I had tried that, and it gave me an error stating that it can't accept UINavigationControllers for that argument.

Comment: @Pilatus but the FlyoutNavigationController is based upon a UIViewController class. ... I suppose that necessarily wouldn't stop it from handling a navigation stack though, so perhaps indeed it's worth a bit more investigation. What I've (so far) tested with the FlyoutNavigationController, though, hasn't resulted in any fruitful results.

Comment: Have a look at the sample app and the code if sample still doesn't explain much.. https://github.com/Clancey/FlyoutNavigation/tree/master/FlyoutNavigationSample/FlyoutNavigationSample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into `FlyoutNavigation` it seems that it is possible to use a `Storyboard`

[image: Using storyboard]

Try downloading the Sample project ([as pointed out by Mohib Sheth](https://github.com/Clancey/FlyoutNavigation/tree/master/FlyoutNavigationSample/FlyoutNavigationSample)) and create a push segment between the button and the second view.

**Using the `PushViewController` method**

If you still want to use the `PushViewController` method make sure that your initial view ( as shown after clicking on a FlyOutNavigation item ) is a `NavigationController`. This `NavigationController` will control the navigation stack for the current page.

Now that the `ViewController` is wrapped by a `NavigationController` you can add a button or just call the `NavigationController.PushViewController` method.

```
PushView.TouchDown += (evt, args) =>
{
    NavigationController.PushViewController(new UIViewController(), true);
};
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: You did give me a bit of inspiration to look more into something, so I'll definitely try out some things once I have the chance tomorrow. Also, I did not know it could work with storyboards! For this current project, I've already gone so far down the foxhole of not having a storyboard that I'm afraid to rip apart my entire project just to implement that, though. When it comes to future projects, though, I'll certainly look at this more! If I can get things figured out, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Update: it's been a few years, and I've honestly completely forgotten about this question. Since posting this question, I've parted ways with the group that was developing this project, and I now lack the ability to even test this answer. ... So, I'm currently at a point where I'm not quite sure what to do with this answer here.

Comment: If you're not sure if this answer either helped you, you should probably close the question. Since this answer was posted 2 years ago I doubt how many people still find use in this answer.